# What is an Approximation Factor?

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

How is an approximation Factor different than time-complexity? I have heard, for example, of polynomial algorithms with exponential factors, what does that mean? Does that mean it is not technically  in polynomial time?

Comment: Where did you hear this term? I don't think it has any standard meaning in this context.

Comment: I found it in a pdf on Lattice based cryptography. The line was "This is a polynomial time algorithm for SVP (and for most other basic lattice problems) that achieves an approximation factor of $2^O(n)$ where n is the dimension of the lattice."   The article is https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=o1OIVeKUOq3asASYwK6IDA&url=https://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/papers/pqc.pdf&ved=0CCIQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNEixufKTnQUuzJsI1N6z6UiZFGJAw and it was under section 1.1 lattice problems and algorithms.

Comment: That says *approximation* factor, not complexity factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have enough reputation points, hence posting as answer.

Perhaps your use of **factor** in two different senses is the source of the confusion. Time is but one factor out of many possible **complexity factors**, such as storage, bandwidth, etc. **Exponential factors** in the case of polynomial algorithms refer to the factors of the terms in the mathematical equation. They do not necessarily imply time as a factor, but they do not exclude it either. It depends on what the algorithm is modeling.

Comment: This deserves to be an answer, why should you've posted it as a comment? It is worth acceptable for this question. Upvoted :)

Comment: To add to your answer I ended up finding by searching fot something else. This which I believe is basically what you are saying https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_factor_approximation_algorithm

Comment: @dylan7: No, this answer is completely unrelated to what you found. What you found is probably more relevant to the thing that made you post this question.

Comment: Well Emacs User said it is the factor of the terms of the function whose big O we take. The wiki I posted said it is a factor of the whole equation. So it's an approximation of a poly algorithm up to the factor. So it's similar.